# regular expression that extracts words from a string

Tags: java, regex, text-segmentation

I want to extract all words from a java String.

word can be written in any european language, and does not contain spaces, only alpha symbols.

it can contain hyphens though.

Comment: Is `o'clock` a word? Is `Modula-2` a word?

Comment: what about `x'x'x'`? is that a "word"? What about `zexcqcewqxc-trmnbynmtrby`?

Comment: @polygenelubricants they are. in the simplest case.

Comment: No, by no means, [0-9] cannot be present in any word. Modula-2 is not a word.

Answer (score 3):

If you aren't tied to regular expressions, also have a look at [BreakIterator](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/BreakIterator.html), in particular the [getWordInstance()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/BreakIterator.html#getWordInstance(java.util.Locale)) method:

> Word boundary analysis is used by search and replace functions, as well as within text editing applications that allow the user to select words with a double click. Word selection provides correct interpretation of punctuation marks within and following words. Characters that are not part of a word, such as symbols or punctuation marks, have word-breaks on both sides.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a variation of `(?<!\S)\S+(?!\S)`, i.e. any maximal sequence of non-whitespace characters.

- Negative lookarounds are used so that it can match "words" at the beginning and end of string
- Substitute your own character class for `\S` to look for something more specific

  - (e.g. `[A-Za-z-]`, etc)

Here's a simple example to illustrate the idea, using `[a-z-]` as the alphabet character class:

```
    String text = "--xx128736f-afasdf2137asdf-12387-kjs-23xx--";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
        "(?<!alpha)alpha+(?!alpha)".replace("alpha", "[a-z-]")
    );
    Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
```

This prints:

```
--xx
f-afasdf
asdf-
-kjs-
xx--
```

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), [Character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

---

#### But what should the alphabet be?

You may have to use the Unicode character classes etc (stay put, researching on topic right now)

Comment: Hmm I think this answer is going nowhere, actually. `(?<!alpha)alpha+(?!alpha)` is just `alpha+`. I may end up deleting this. Feedbacks?

Comment: it's going somewhere, as it prints something. Waiting for your final solution to see it in work.

Answer (score 0):

This will match a single word:

```
`([^\s]+)`
```

Comment: That depends on the definition of "word". Also, it will match the empty string.

`\S+` is better, or `(\S+)` if you want to capture it.

Comment: Surely your regex matches one or more whitespace characters?

Comment: `\s` matches whitespace, `\S` matches non-whitespace.